# How to make the picture follow my finger WP7 Silverlight?

Tags: windows-phone-7, drag-and-drop, gesture

Something like dragging and dropping an image

Is there a basic sample that I can use for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OnManipulationStarter`, `OnManipulationDelta` and `OnManipulationCompleted` events with `TranslateTransform` on some object to move it below your finger.

Also, advanced stuff will be [MultiTouch Behavior for Windows Phone 7](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/07/04/multitouch-behavior-for-windows-phone-7-videos-wp7dev.aspx)

Comment: Thank for help, that was helpful... Now I have a large scale picture, 4 times larger than the phone screen... When dragging, I want to see all part of the enlarged picture... What happens is a part of the picture appears, and when I drag that part to see other parts, I just see black region. Any ideas??

Comment: First of all, max size of `GPU` rendered control is 2048x2048. Secondly, if parent container is `Grid` it will crop it's children. Use `Canvas` instead.

Comment: my code to enlarge the image was: `image.width *= 4; image.height*=4;` I'm new to silverlight, could you tell me how to use Canvas? Thanks.

Comment: Put image inside `Canvas` instead a `Grid`. I think, the better way is to use `RenderTransform` to manipulate on position, scale and so on.

Comment: Another point please.. When dragging, I need to know the new position of the picture. `Canvas.GetLeft` returns the same value even if the position of the image changed..

Comment: `OnManipulationDelta` event args has delta and total manipulation you can use to find current image position

Comment: I've just tried `OnManipulationDelta` I could get the delta or difference in the location. I still need the location of the dragged image, need x,y that should vary during translation.

Comment: I always get a value of 0 even if the image is moving.